# grep a variable in if condition

Tags: shell, ksh

So currently i need to grep a  "." from a variable and if it is successful than do some work. So currently i am using this code

```
if echo "$arg3" | grep -iv '\.' ;
then
FS="'$arg4.$arg3'"
fi
```

Here i will pass  the value in $arg3 like test and look for the "." in the variable and if it is not there than add a substring $arg4 and store it to the another variable.
SO my problemis, it is working but when i run my script it will print the $arg3 value as well.

Thanks in regards,
 Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the grep output to null as below:

```
if echo "$arg3" | grep -iv '\.' > /dev/null 2>&1
```